# Fail to build atom/electron on Windows 7

Tags: python, node.js, electron

Try to [build atom/electron on Windows](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/development/build-instructions-windows.md) 7, but failed.

OS Environment:

- Windows 7
- VS 2013 Update 5
- Python 2.7
- Node.js 4.2.3
- Git 2.6.4
- atom/electron - Latest pull (2015.12.17)

It failed when running the bootstrap script "**$ python bootstrap.py -v**", the screenshot is here:

[image]

Trying to find a way through, any help will be appreciated.

-- dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way...:

### Situation failed one: "can't open file"

According to the official documentation: [Build Instructions (Windows)](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/development/build-instructions-windows.md)

```
$ python script\bootstrap.py -v
```

the result will be:

```
D:\Program Files\Python27\python.exe: can't open file 'scriptbootstrap.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

### Situation failed two: "WindowsError: [Error 3]...."

Pay attention to this:

```
$ cd script
$ python bootstrap.py -v
```

I cd into the script folder, and run the bootstrap script, and failed.

## Situation OK: Use "/" instead of "\"

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Explanations are welcome...

--dean